# SQLZoo 12 SELECT from WORLD Tutorial

Tags: mysql, sql, case, sql-like, case-when

I'm trying to answer #12 on SQLZoo from SELECT from WORLD tutorial, (http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SQLZOO:SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial)

It asks to "Show the name and the continent - but substitute Eurasia for Europe and Asia; substitute America - for each country in North America or South America or Caribbean. Show countries beginning with A or B"

I'm new to SQL and cant seem to figure this one out. Could someone please help explain to me how to solve this? I'm mostly getting stuck on the CASE statements and how to do multiple values for the conditions.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Add what you have so far here, also add the data example and question. All what you ask has to be on stackoverflow. External links are only to be used for answers and code fiddles (still with the code posted here) , not for questions.

Comment: best to state your real target server type else the answers of SQLZoo questions get scolded for disobeying meaningless generic-ness

Comment: I apologize, as I'm new to the platform. I'll be sure to keep your comments in mind as I move forward.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but hope it helps

```
select name,
Replace(continent,
case 
   when continent in('North America', 'South America', 'Caribbean', 'Europe', 'Asia') then continent 
   else '' end, 
case 
   when continent in('Europe', 'Asia') then 'Eurasia'
   when continent in('North America', 'South America', 'Caribbean') then 'America' 
   else '' end) as continent 
from World where name like 'A%' or name like 'B%';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It didn't work so I will try another way hopefully it works. Will update this if I get it right. I appreciate you taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
name as Name,
CASE WHEN continent IN ('Europe', 'Asia') THEN 'Eurasia'
WHEN continent IN ('North America', 'South America', 'Caribbean') THEN 'America'
ELSE continent END as Continent
FROM world
WHERE name BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,  
CASE WHEN continent IN ('Europe', 'Asia') THEN 'Eurasia'
           WHEN continent IN ('North America', 'South America') THEN 'America' 
           WHEN continent = 'Caribbean' THEN 'America'
           ELSE continent END
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' 
OR name LIKE 'B%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is:

```sql
 SELECT name,
       CASE WHEN continent in ('Europe','Asia') THEN 'Eurasia'
            WHEN continent in ('North America','South America','Caribbean') THEN 'America'
            ELSE continent END
  FROM world
 WHERE name LIKE 'A%' or name LIKE 'B%'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name,
   CASE WHEN continent IN ('Europe', 'Asia') THEN 'Eurasia'
        WHEN continent IN ('North America', 'South America', 'Caribbean') THEN 'America'
        ELSE continent END
FROM world
WHERE name LIKE 'A%' or name LIKE 'B%'
```